# $\int_{|z| = 2 }\frac{4z^7-1}{z^8-2z+1} dz= ?$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, wolfram-alpha

**Problem:** Compute $\int_{|z|=2} \frac{4z^7 - 1}{z^8 - 2z + 1}dz$.

**Attempt:** I notice that if $w = z^8 - 2z + 1$ then $dw = 2 (4z^8 - 1) dz$ so $$I=\int_{|z|=2} \frac{4z^7 - 1}{z^8 - 2z + 1}dz = \frac{1}{2}\int_C \frac{1}{w}dw$$ over the closed curve $C = \{ (2e^{i \theta})^8 - 2 (2e^{i \theta}) + 1 \in \mathbb{C} : 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \}$.

At this point, I know that $\int_C \frac{1}{w} dw = 2\pi i \cdot (\text{winding number of }C\text{ around w = 0})$ so $I = \frac{1}{2} 2\pi i \cdot 8 = 8 \pi i$. Is this not correct?

When I try to verify my answer using Wolfram Alpha, I can get a complex number with nonzero real part: [Wolfram link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%5B0...2pi%5D%20%284%282e%5E%28ix%29%29%5E7%20-%201%29%2F%28%282e%5E%28ix%29%29%5E8%20-%202%282e%5E%28ix%29%29%20%2B%201%292e%5E%28ix%29%20*%20i%20*%20dx)

Maybe Wolfram Alpha is just approximating this integral up to some error bound so their approximation terminates without realizing the real part is actually $0$?

Comment: That is just numerical error. You are correct that the contour integral is indeed equal to $8\pi i$. The sum of the residues in $|z|<2$ is equal to $4$.

Comment: A slightly better way is to use the residue at infinity.

Comment: @KStarGamer I considered doing your proposed method of summing the residues in $|z| < 2$. But by hand, this would take forever (since it is an 8 degree polynomial) during a timed-exam setting right?

Comment: @mathlover314 It would indeed, however, I used the approach mentioned above of the residue at infinity since it can be shown that all the roots of $z^8-2z+1$ are within this disk.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I just learned about the Residue at Infinity through your comment. Thank you for mentioning that. Quick clarification question: is $-Res(f,\infty) = \sum_{a_k \text{ poles}} Res(f,a_k)$ even if $a_k$ is not a simple pole of $f$? That is, if the denominator of $f$ is a polynomial with repeated roots can I still use the Residue at infinity technique?

Comment: The residue theorem applies even if you don't have simple poles. I can write an answer when I return home later in the evening outlining this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residue at infinity serves as a sort of "dual" to the residue at zero. Namely,

$$\mathrm{Res}(f(z), \infty) = - \mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z} \right), 0 \right). $$

Recall that the residue theorem looks at the contributions of singularities inside the contour. But $\infty$ is outside of our contour. How do we fix this? Easy - reverse the orientation. That's where the minus sign comes in.

Let $f(z) = \frac{4z^7 - 1}{z^8 - 2z + 1}.$ Then

\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{1}{z} \right) &= \frac{\frac{4}{z^7} - 1}{\frac{1}{z^8} - \frac{2}{z} + 1} \\
&= \frac{4z - z^8}{1 - 2z^7 + z^8}
\end{align*}

Computing the needed value is easy. Thanks to some nice cancellation,

$$ \lim_{z \to 0} z\cdot \frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z} \right) = 4 $$

and $\mathrm{Res}(f(z), \infty) = -4.$

Let $\gamma$ be the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin (our contour). Now since $\infty$ is outside $\gamma$, we instead integrate over $-\gamma$ by reversing orientation so that $\infty$ is inside $-\gamma.$ So,

\begin{align*}
\oint\limits_{\gamma} f(z) \ dz &= -\oint\limits_{-\gamma} f(z) \ dz \\
&= -2\pi i \mathrm{Res}(f(z), \infty) \\
&= 8\pi i
\end{align*}

as needed!

Answer (score 1):

An expedient route is to make use of Rouche and the Argument Principle.

With $\gamma:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ given by $\gamma(t)=2\cdot\exp\big(2\pi i\cdot t\big)$ and
$p(z):=z^8 -2z +1$, notice for any $z$ with modulus $2$
$\big\vert z \big\vert^8 \gt 5 \geq \big\vert -2\cdot z +1\big\vert $ so $p(z)$ and $z^8$ have the same number of roots in $B\big(0,2\big)$ per Rouche.

Then the Argument Principle says
$8 =n\big(p\circ\gamma,0\big) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz$
$\implies  8 \pi i=\int_{\gamma} \frac{4z^7 - 1}{z^8 - 2z + 1}dz$